# Unable to compare two dates java,Invalid conversion while converting String to Date using SimpleDateFormat "dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"

Tags: java, date, compare, simpledateformat

In my application I need to compare two different dates given in below formats.

Inputs:
there are 2 input dates in String format.

```
String actual="11/12/2012 11:26:04 AM";
String expected="21/12/2012 09:49:12 AM";
```

I am trying to use below java code for comparision.

---

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a");
Date date1 = format.parse(actual);
System.out.println("Formated date1 is: "+format.format(date1).toString());       
// prints  :  01/01/2012 11:26:04 AM  Why????

Date date2= format.parse(expected);
System.out.println("Formated date2 is: "+format.format(date2).toString());        
// prints :  01/01/2012 09:49:12 AM  Why????

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);
if( !(cal1.compareTo(cal2)<=0))
{
 result=false;
 String errMsg +="Actual:"+actual+" date is not before or equal to expected:"+expected+" date\n";
 System.out.println(errMsg);
}
```

---

But the above code is not working as expected. please check the wrong output mentioned in comments

I think there is something wrong with the formatting.
can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your format should be :

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

Notice `year` in **lowercase y**

Comment: Hi Kevin Bowersox and GanGnaMStYleOverFlow,

Comment: Accepting a correct answer is preferred to thanks.  Accept one of the answers that helped you out.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

The Ys should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has really nice methods, like `isBefore()`

[image]

```
String actual = "11/12/2012 11:26:04 AM";
String expected = "21/12/2012 09:49:12 AM";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a");
DateTime dateTime1 = fmt.parseDateTime(actual);
DateTime dateTime2 = fmt.parseDateTime(expected);


if (dateTime1.isBefore(dateTime2)) {
    System.out.println("awesome");
}
```